# Mysql set SYSTEM timezone

Tags: mysql, linux

When I type on my server in command line:

```
date
```

I get

```
Sat Nov 12 22:31:02 CET 2016
```

and that's correct.

When I do in MySql:

```
SET @@session.time_zone='system'; SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

I get:

```
2016-11-12 16:31:38
```

When I do in MySql:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

I get SYSTEM and SYSTEM

So why is Mysql showing different time?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted mysqld and everything is fine now. I think timezone on the server might have been changed since the last restart of mysqld. Server was managed by someone else so I am not sure.